# Texmaker - changing ctrl + Q shortcut effect does not work (Windows 10)

Tags: texmaker, windows, shortcut

By default, CTRL + Q means quit in Texmaker. If I change the shortcut of some action in preferences to CTRL + Q, this key combination has no longer any effect. Other key combinations work for me for the same action, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the user manual
Defaults keyboard shorscuts [sic] (*:can be modified …

This implies file menu command shortcuts canNOT be modified

Control Q is not available as its "Reserved" for "Exit : Ctrl+Q"
Equally you cant use Ctrl+N as it's also reserved for New
etc. for the file shortcuts as listed Ctrl+O Ctrl+S Ctrl+W
whilst not listed in the manual I also can't change Ctrl+P